# embeddable flash based mp3 player

Tags: flash, streaming, mp3

I need to serve audio content (not music though, more like podcasts; human speech), and I'm thinking of using a flash-based player to let users hear the content without having to download it.

I need a free embeddable flash based mp3 player. Any suggestions?

Because it's not music, I don't care about playlist (I don't want them, they will get in the way), and I need a seek-bar (if that's what you call it), I also don't want it to display the file name or title any crazy thing like that, just a play/pause button and a seek bar.

Or, alternatively, if it's not very complicated, I might try to make one myself. Does anyone have experience building such a thing to give me an insight on how hard it would be?

**UPDATE**
I'm looking at this one http://www.macloo.com/examples/audio_player/

Though, I don't know who made it, and whether or not it's free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The player you have found is also available from this page: http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone (this might be a more recent version), it's released under the MIT license (e.g. it's free).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Dewplayer](http://www.alsacreations.fr/dewplayer-en), or [Flash Mp3 Player](http://flash-mp3-player.net/)

Both are free and good

Comment: +1 for dewplayer - it's stable, 5 KB and comes in several modifications for almost any taste.

Comment: can i add `http` streaming url with in `dewplayer` ?

Answer (score 1):

I like the flash mp3 player from [1pixelout](http://www.1pixelout.net/code/audio-player-wordpress-plugin/), there's a [tutorial here](http://www.macloo.com/examples/audio_player/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend A2 mp3 player - http://flashstall.com/7. It was released just a few days ago.