# Play more than one song in a web page

Tags: javascript, audio-player

I'm working on my HTML and Javascript project and I wanted to add music for the website..

Is there any way I can put more than one song in the code to be played?  And is there anyway that the song will continue when openning the next page?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? Music on webpages is annoying, yes, but this is still a real question.

Answer (score 3):

Without using Flash, you are bound to a new HTML5 technique `<audio/>`, which is supported in Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome 3+, and Opera 10+. Here is an example:

```
<audio src="path/to/some/audio.file" autoplay>  
  This is a fall back for old browsers, here you could implement a Flash based audio player
</audio>
```

I'm not sure if it is possible to continue the song when opening the next page, maybe you could store player data in a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790252/free-audio-players-for-website-streaming/2790294) with some good answers.  The comments in that question list many duplicate questions as well.  Many of those answers require HTML5.  There are also various [Flash-based answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415889/embeddable-flash-based-mp3-player) as well.

If you want the song to continue when opening the next page you will need to use [frames](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/frames/_FRAMESET.html) (easy) or make your website entirely AJAX-driven (more tedious).